# How find duplicate elements in an array with in a floating point precision?

Tags: arrays, sorting

How find duplicate elements in an array with in a floating point precision? e.g. a=[1.2 1 3 3.15 6 8] should give me index locations idx=[1 3] where 1 nd 1.2 are treated as same and similarly 3 and 3.15 are treated as same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of integer array, finding duplicates is a trivial problem.
Finding duplicates with double precision sound definitely ambigious.

For example, you have values:

```
1.0 1.15 1.3
```

Which of them are supposed to be duplicated? All three of them?

If we remove the second value, then all of them become non-duplicated? That's a strange behaviour.

Let's describe what duplicated value in this case like this:

> In an array of **rounded** integer values the value X is being duplicated if there is at least one value with the same value.

It is important because there can be another logic like difference in `epsilon`. For example, for `epsilon = 0.2`, 2.9 and 3.4 will not be duplicated. However, in case of rounded values - they will.

Since you haven't specified your language, I will use C#. It is easy to translate it to C, C++ or Java.
Now we can implement it this way:

```
double[] doubleArr = new double[] { 1.2, 1.0, 3.0, 3.15, 6.0, 8.0 };
int[] integerArr;
List<int> duplicatedIndices = new List<int>();

integerArr = doubleArr.Select(x => (int)Math.Round(x));

for (int i = 0; i < integerArr.Length; i++)
{
    if (integerArr.Count(x => x == integerArr[i]) > 1) // don't forget about self
        duplicatedIndices.Add(i);
}
```

For an array [1.2, 1.0, 3.0, 3.15, 6.0, 8.0] it will return

```
0, 1, 2, 3
```

because all of them have a duplicated value.

Answer (score 0):

Python, quick and dirty:

```
list_a=[1.2 1 3 3.15 6 8]  
holding_list=[]

for x in list_a:
    if int(x) in holding_list:
        pass
    else:
        holding_list.append(x)

print holding_list
```

Instead of `int` rounding off values can be done depending upon what output is desired

Answer (score -1):

Hope the elements in your array are sorted.   Cast the elements to `int` when trying to find the duplicates.  Integers will not consider the decimal digits.